# Pandas: Split large file into seperate files by Date, preserving original ordering.

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a very large dataframe, with a date Index , that covers a period of multiple years by day. With each day containing multiple values.

```
      Date (DT_index)   Description   Value1
  1      2015-01-12     stringvalue    10
  2      2015-01-12     stringvalue    12
  3      2015-01-12     stringvalue    14
  4      2015-02-12     stringvalue    16
  5      2015-02-12     stringvalue   348
  6      2015-09-12     stringvalue     1
  7      2015-09-12     stringvalue     9
                  (.....)
8456     2017-11-03     stringvalue    10
8457     2017-11-03     stringvalue   111
8458     2017-11-04     stringvalue    29
```

What I want is to split this csv into seperate files, based on month/year. 
(So a files like:  12-2015.csv, 01-2016.csv, 02-2016.csv)

I've loaded the large csv into a pandas df and grouped it by month like so

```
dfgp = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='M'))
```

But the only operations available to me seem things like 'sum' or 'avg'. 
Which I do not want, I want to slice the large DF by month, not perform .apply operations that changes or aggregates the data.

I've also tried this code:

```
dfgp = [group[1] for group in df.groupby(df.index.date)]

for x in result:
    name = str(x.index.date.month.year)
    x.to_csv(name, sep=';')
```

This method came very close. I had 2 issues with it. 
1. My naming method did not work:

```
'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'month'
```

2. When I remove my name method it iterates over the files. But the groups were made by day (example: 2015-12-13, with 6 entries, rather than 2015-12-alldays with 238 entries)

I to correct the last issue with this code:

```
result = [group[1] for group in df.groupby(df.index.date.month)]
```

But that just threw the same error as before:

```
'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'month'
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You don't actually want to group by month, you just want to index by month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try:

```
for n,g in df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M')):
    name = n.strftime('%Y%m') + '.csv'
    g.to_csv(name, sep=';')
```

Comment: You mean to_c*s*v ;)

Answer (score 2):

There is probably a better (more pandathonic) way to do this:

```
import os

# this just assumes that you want to save where the 
# current file is located
csv_path = 'path\to\your.csv'
data_path = os.path.dirname(csv_path)

# read the csv and add a simple string column for indexing
df = pd.read_csv(csv_path)
df['date_filters'] = df['Date'].str.strftime('%m-%Y')

# iterate over the months present
for month in df['date_filters'].unique():
    # slice out the month
    month_df = df[df['date_filters'] == month]
    # drop the string column you added before saving
    month_df.drop('date_filters', inplace=True, axis=1)
    # make the path and save
    month_path = os.path.join(data_path, month+'.csv')
    month_df.to_csv(month_path, index=False)
```